# Clear calculator display javascript after calculation

Tags: javascript, function, calculator

I'm doing a beginner calculator project in JavaScript, and I'm trying to figure out a way to clear the display on the start of a new calculation. For example:

- press "1 + 1"
- press "="
- display will now be "2"

If I now want to start a new calculation and I press 3 for example, this will append to the result i.e display will now be "23".

How can I force the display to remove the result when starting a new calculation?

I was wondering if I could do it with an if statement:

```js
function resetDisplay() {
  if(//previous key pressed was "=") {
    on next key press, remove calculation result and only show new input
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my JS code
`

```
//function that displays values in the calculator window
function disp(val) {
  document.getElementById("display").value+=val;
}

//function for clearing the display
function clr() {
  document.getElementById("display").value="";
}

//function for backspace
function del() {
  let dis = document.getElementById("display").value;
  document.getElementById("display").value = dis.substring(0, dis.length - 1);
}

//function for evaluation
function solve() {
  let numericalExpression = document.getElementById("display").value;
  let result = eval(numericalExpression);
  document.getElementById("display").value = result;
}

//function to clear display after calculation

function resetDisplay() {}
```

Also the link to the entire [project on codepen](https://codepen.io/amark16/pen/BapYRMb?editors=1010)

How exactly do I define the start of a new calculation? Basically I want the key pressed after the "=" button has been pressed to remove the previous calculation.

Answer (score 0):

```
var calcDone=false;

function display(val){
resetdisplay();
var valu = document.getElementById(val).value;
document.getElementById("display").value+=valu;
}
function clear(){
document.getElementById("display").value="";
}
function calculation(){
var equation = document.getElementById("display").value;
var sol = eval(equation);
document.getElementById("display").value=sol;
calcDone=true;

}
//TO RESET after Calculation
function resetdisplay(){
if(calcDone){
    document.getElementById("display").value="";
    calcDone=false;
}
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for my calculator:

first you assign a `boolean` variable and then clear the display depending on the state (`true` or `false`) of the variable .

In my case I returned it `true` after the calculation.

in case of new input after calculation you have to check the state of the variable first with an `if` statement. if the value is `true` then clear the display first and  append the new input and change the state of boolean variable to `false` so that we can input more numbers.

it looks somethng like this :

```js
const display = document.getElementById("display);

let dontWithIt;        

function moveToDisplay(input){      
  if (doneWithIt=== true){
      display.value= "";
      display.value += input;
      doneWithIt = false;
    } else{
      display.value += input;
      }
  };
  
  function calculate(){
     display.value = eval(display.value);
     doneWithIt = true;
  };
```